# Loop through list of resources to create new resources terraform

Tags: loops, terraform, pagerduty

I have tried to get this to work, but Terraform keeps yelling at me.  I am trying to use a loop create a bunch of new resources that need to reference an existing resource id.  However, terraform seems to not want to create the resource.

*note this uses the terraform pagerduty provider*

My list of "sites":

```
locals {
  sites = [
    "site1",
    "site2"
  ]
}
```

My resource block:

```
resource "pagerduty_service_event_rule" "rule" {
  for_each = toset(local.sites)
  service  = "pagerduty_service.${each.key}.id"

... rest of block
```

When I run a `apply` it looks like it's going to work, but it times out (eventually giving me a 403 error).

I've determined that the issue is because the service resource attribute for the service `id` is invalid because it is in double quotes.

How can I properly iterate through this list to create these resources properly?

Thx

Comment: "keeps yelling at me" - what does it mean? Do you get any errors? What are the exact errors you get? What is `pagerduty_service`? Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: @marcin i did mention that it eventually gives me a 403 error (no permissions). Pagerduty is a paging service, though what it is shouldn't matter.

what i need to be able to do is create the resource attribute id string in some way that doesn't use quotes (ie. replace `"pagerduty_service.${each.key}.id"` with something that works the same but doesn't use that kind of interpolation.

Comment: maybe it is also helpful to specify that the resource I am trying to reference in the `service` line already exists.  I am trying to create a new resource that is linked to the existing `service` resource.

Comment: `pagerduty_service` meters because you have `"pagerduty_service.${each.key}.id"` which is not a valid TF code. The same errors that you get matter as well.

Answer (score 0):

so i managed to figure this out and it was much more simple than I expected..  I just needed to change the local sites `list` to a `map` and **not use quotes on the values**.

```
locals {
  sites = [
    site1 = pagerduty_service.site1.id
    site2 = pagerduty_service.site2.id
  ]
}

resource "pagerduty_service_event_rule" "rule" {
  for_each = local.sites
  service  = each.value

... rest of block
```